# Data analysis (chart)

Tags: algorithm, charts, pattern-recognition

How to recognize start-point and end-point if data looks like at picture. I want to recognize that wave at axis Z(blue) 50-125 has start at 50 and end at 125. Axis Y (green) wave starts at 125 and ends at 175. I cant use method when it simply does not equal zero because of noise in signal.

I assume wave starts with value 0 and ends with value 0. Data are represented as descrete values like this Point[time,value]
[image: Visualization of my data]

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach for digital signal processing is to analyse the data using a [fast Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) algorithm.

Briefly, it quickly breaks up the signal into discrete frequencies, so in your case you would look for the very low frequencies in the data.